# I am getting this error "Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." When trying the code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function UseState() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    decrementCount();
  }, []);

  function decrementCount() {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount - 1);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={decrementCount()}>-</button>
      <span>{count}</span>
      <button>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UseState;
```

I am getting the error in the browser's console:

> Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

If am removing the `function decrementCount() { setCount((prevCount) => prevCount - 1); }` and `button onClick={decrementCount()}` from `<button > - </button>` then I am not getting any error.

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: `onClick={decrementCount()}` ---> `onClick={() => decrementCount()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you passed `decrementCount` as a handler like this `onClick={decrementCount()}`, you're passing the **call of the decrementCount**, not the function itself. And because your function triggers rerender of the component, your component starts to rerender infinitly.

To fix this, pass just the function name to the onClick like this:

```
onClick={decrementCount}
```

Comment: Tq @Robert Hovhannisyan I made the change you mentioned and it worked.

Comment: @RamKumar you're welcome bro, at the start we all made that mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing paranthesis "()" from the method in onClick prop. Do update me if it works.

Comment: Please try to explain how this can help to fix the problem rather than just how to fix it.